# how to traverse to the ancestor and back to child in selenium xpath?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have written xpath as below :

```
//span[contains(text(),'Preview')]/..//..//..//*[contains(text(),'Edit')]
```

How can I replace '`/..//..//..//`' with functions like ancestor, parent, preceding..

Here is the html:

```
 <div class="parent">
          <div class="test">
                    <button class="test1">
                    <span>Edit</span>
                    </button>
          </div>

          <div class="test">
          </div>

          <div class="test">
                    <button class="test2">
                    <span>Preview</span>
                    </button>
          </div>
    <div>
```

Comment: Which node exactly you want to select?

Comment: I want to select Edit by taking Preview as reference

Comment: Which node exactly? `div`, `button`, `span`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following xpath:

```
//div[@class='parent' and contains(., 'Preview')]//button[@class='test1']//span[text()='Edit']
```

Answer (score 0):

Go up to ancestor div class parent and then down.

```
//div/span[contains(text(),'Preview')]/ancestor::div[class='parent']//*[contains(text(),'Edit')]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one to select required node

```
//div[.//span="Preview"]/preceding-sibling::div//span[.="Edit"]
```